# Realm - module file was created by an older version of compiler

Tags: xcode, swift, realm

I use latest version of xcode and swift 2.2. One of my projects, which I havent open for several month now not building, because of error 
`module file was created by an older version of compiler`

I tried the following

1. Removed realm frameworks from project, then download the latest version from realm.io and copy the new frameworks to project
2. Building realm by `build.sh build` from github sources with `REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=2.2` and adding to project

Neither of these helped, still got error.

Any advices ?

Comment: `module file was created by an older version` This often means the Xcode project has obsolete information. Try cleaning it (menu Product, Clean) then rebuild.

Comment: tried, still the same error

Answer (score 7):

Can you try the following?

- Delete derived data
- Clean the build folder (click on Xcode's *Product* menu while holding down the Option key, and choose the *Clean Build Folder* menu item)

Sometimes simply performing a clean build isn't sufficient to flush the invalid intermediate products or cached data.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when upgrading from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0, specifically for Realm Swift cocoapod. I think this solution should work for this general issue. Here is what worked for me:

(1) Go to derived data folder /Users/(yourUserName)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

(2) Select project with error

(3) Delete

(4) Clean project

(5) Run

Cleaning initially did not work for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when used Swift 3.2 in my project. After upgrading to Swift 4.0 issue disappeared. Cleaning project folder, derived data, restarting Mac - nothing helped.