# Can't load XCTest for Realm testing

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, realm, xctest

When I build my test target and try to execute Realm tests I"m getting: Symbol not found: _RLMErrorDomain when it tries to load the test bundle. I've add pod 'Realm' to my test target in my Podfile.

I initially was getting the error, Symbol not found _OBJC_CLASS_$_RLMObject but I resolved that from changing my pod file from pod 'Realm/headers' to pod 'Realm'. I found that issue/solution here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1538

I've recently converted over to Realm to replace my CoreData stack based approach. This unit test worked fine for testing the ManagedObject version of my model objects and object adapters.

Here is the generalized PodFile content:

```
platform :ios, '8.2'

def shared_pods
    pod 'Realm'
end

target ‘project’ do

    shared_pods

    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'Instabug'
    pod 'Intercom'
    pod 'iCarousel'
    pod 'HPGrowingTextView'


end

target ‘projectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    shared_pods
end

target ‘Project WatchKit Extension' do

pod 'IGInterfaceDataTable'

end

target ‘Project WatchKit App' do

end

post_install do |installer_representation|  
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|  
        target.build_configurations.each do |config| 
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'  
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: It may be helpful to see your Podfile.

Comment: Sometimes CocoaPods doesn't get rid of invalid cached state properly. Could you try the instructions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919047/realm-module-file-was-created-by-an-older-version-of-compiler/37928150#37928150) and see if anything changes?

Comment: If that doesn't work, the `pod` commands in the [Realm troubleshooting guide](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#cocoapods) may also be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first suggestion no change. But interesting enough, since I posted this I've loaded up Xcode8 Beta and tried the same project and it loads up my test. My specific test then is failing for other reasons, but at least i seem to be one step closer to implementing a Realm based unit test.  I will also try the second suggestion back on my Xcode 7 setup too though.