# Build realm for Swift 3 & Xcode 8

Tags: swift, realm

I am following the steps given [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3796) to build realm to be used in an iOS project, I am using Xcode 8 beta 3 :

I get these warnings :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file .../Realm.framework/Realm, missing required architecture x86_64 in file .../Realm.framework/Realm (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file .../RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift, missing required architecture x86_64 in file .../RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift (2 slices)
```

and this error

```
Lipo: -remove's specified would result in an empty fat file
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hi Carpsen90,

I just realized that there were directions that you linked to. Would you be willing to share which beta of Xcode 8 you are using? Also, in Xcode --> Preferences menu --> Locations tab, do you have the Xcode 8.0 command line tools selected?

Comment: @AustinZ I am using Xcode 8 beta 3, and command lines are set to Xcode 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try these updated instructions, which should work for Beta 3?

1. Clone the Realm Cocoa git repository: `git clone https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git`
2. Open the Xcode project. Click on the `Realm` project, then the `RealmSwift` target, then the 'Build Settings' tab, and set `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `Yes` (if building for Swift 2.3) or `No` (if building for Swift 3).
3. From the directory containing the git repository, run the following command: `sh build.sh TARGET`, where `TARGET` is one of the following: `ios-swift`, `osx-swift`, `tvos-swift`, or `watchos-swift`, depending on what platform you are building for.
4. Once the build has completed, go to the 'build' directory, then the directory named after the platform for which you built (e.g. 'ios').
5. Open the 'swift-2.3' or 'swift-3.0' directory (depending on which version you built for).
6. Drag `RealmSwift.framework` and `Realm.framework` into your project, as per step 2 in the instructions [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-22), and do steps 3 and 4.

If these don't work please do post a comment.

Comment: Is there an easy way to integrate this into a `carthage` workflow?

Comment: There are no more compile errors, but I get this runtime error dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  `Referenced from: .../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/761AECC6-C62D-4AE0-90EB-518A91736F3D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D7FFF785-CD14-46CF-A7A4-B0648B822FAF/RealmApp.app/RealmApp
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: @catalandres I'll look into what it would take to get this working with Carthage.

Comment: @Carpsen90 You may need to go to your app target, then the General tab, then add the two frameworks to the "Embedded Binaries" section. If, after doing so, the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section has duplicate entries for the frameworks, delete the duplicates. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @AustinZ there are no duplicates, should I keep this line in build.sh `CODESIGN_PARAMS="CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO"` ?

Comment: @Carpsen90 I wouldn't delete that line if you hadn't added it. If there are no duplicates, I assume that `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` each show up once in both the "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" sections. Assuming that's true, do you still get any errors?

Comment: @AustinZ I haven't deleted that line. `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` do show up only once in "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". I still get the runtime error mentionned above

Comment: @Carpsen90 I'll have to think about it some more and get back to you. One final thing - can you try deleting your derived data and cleaning your build folder (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919047/realm-module-file-was-created-by-an-older-version-of-compiler/37928150#37928150))?

Comment: @AustinZ yes I've done that, and thank you for your time, I do appreciate it

Comment: Getting this: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/mike/Projects/realm-cocoa/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/weak_realm_notifier.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

** BUILD FAILED **

Answer (score 2):

In order to get Swift 3 versions of `Realm` and `RealmSwift`, I had to explicitly target `master`, set `submodules` to `true`, *and* include a `post_install` hook to set the Swift version:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'TARGET_NAME' do
    pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
    pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me and also avoided compiling error I was getting when only specifying pod 'RealmSwift' and the post install hook. I think that Realm website should update the documentation with these instructions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Realm using Cocoapods and this pods:

> pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master'
>
> pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master'

and while running the application don't select convert to swift 3

Comment: Tried it but getting this `If you're using Realm and/or RealmSwift from a git branch, please add 'submodules: true' to
their entries in your Podfile.` So I added `:submodules => true`. The project is already in Swift 3 so I can't downgrade the code

Comment: So when running the app and ignoring the compiler errors, I get this `“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.`

Comment: yes, but I ignored it and have been using Realm normally and in my case it works.

Comment: In your case the base project is not converted to Swift 3 right?

Comment: base project is convert but realm pods not.

Comment: Are you using the current release version of CocoaPods, or the beta?

If you are using the release version (v. 1.0.1), you need to explicitly set the `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` flag on the CocoaPod target. This can be done by clicking on the `Pods` project, clicking on the `RealmSwift` target, going to the 'Build Settings' tab, and changing the flag to `Yes` or `No`.

Comment: @AustinZ I am using coacoapods `1.0.1` and `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` is set to `Yes`. As for this question I am trying to build Realm myself, I wouldn't mind if either solution worked.