# How to build Realm using Swift 2.3?

Tags: swift, swift2, realm, building

I have already change toolchain to swift 2.3 by

> export PATH=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin:"${PATH}"

And did

Open the Xcode project -> Click on the Realm project -> RealmSwift target -> 'Build Settings' tab -> set Use Legacy Swift Language Version to Yes (if building for Swift 2.3) or No (if building for Swift 3).

as [Build realm for Swift 3 & Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696369/build-realm-for-swift-3-xcode-8/38707357#38707357) says.

But what I get is still swift 3.0 version.

Any idea?

---

I looked into build.sh and found out the export path doesn't work as in xcrun swift, which was used by realm to get swift version, it was still 2.2 or 3.0, depending which toolchain was used.

Comment: How are you attempting to build Realm? Using CocoaPods, Carthage, from within Xcode, or using Realm's build.sh script?

Comment: @bdash I used the build.sh in Realm folder.

Comment: Consider CocoaPods/Carthage it will take you 3 seconds to integrate Realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build Realm from the master branch with Swift 2.3, set the `REALM_SWIFT_VERSION` environment variable to `2.3` when building. For instance, to build for OS X:

```
REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=2.3 sh build.sh osx
```

Realm's build scripts will determine which Xcode version to use based on the value of the `REALM_SWIFT_VERSION` environment variable, so there's no need to modify your `PATH` variable.

Comment: and for ios is: REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=2.3 sh build.sh ios-swift  ??

Answer (score 1):

I have chosen @bdash answer as the best one. However, if you want to keep using swift 2.3 in command line. You can do

> export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3

then use

> sh build.sh osx-swift

@bdash answer only affects realm. So I think it is better than mine. My answer is inspired by Keith Smiley, who pointed out that I could use

> xcrun --toolchain "com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3" swiftc -v

to get 2.3 works.

> the toolchain info is in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/ToolchainInfo.plist