# How can you build RealmSwift for Swift 2.3 from sources using Xcode 8 IDE?

Tags: swift, realm, xcode8

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888454/how-to-build-realm-using-swift-2-3) that it is possible to build RealmSwift for swift 2.3 from the command-line.
I have RealmSwift as a dependent project within my workspace.
Is there a tag or commit of [realm-cocoa](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) that has the required `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3` buildSetting in `Realm.xcodeproj` to build my project within the Xcode 8 IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's not possible to override an Xcode subproject's `SWIFT_VERSION` within the IDE. You can specify `SWIFT_VERSION` when invoking `xcodebuild`, which should also propagate to Xcode subprojects, but I don't know of any way to do that from the Xcode GUI.

I'd recommend either using an alternative form of installation (CocoaPods, Carthage or prebuilt binaries) or to fork [`realm-cocoa`](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa), changing the value of `SWIFT_VERSION` and using that fork as your Xcode subproject.

I'd also recommend filing a radar so that Apple can be made aware of this unfortunate limitation!

To answer your other question, no there have never been any releases of Realm where `SWIFT_VERSION` was set to `2.3` in the Xcode project.